# Why would one line of code work but the next line not, sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, office365

In the attached code, I am going through worksheets with CodeName greater than "Sheet6" and looking for rows that match the criteria (expiry date > Date AND order status = "Filled")  It works fine except the line that puts the CodeName of the sheet where matches are found works sometimes and other times not.

This code also finds rows to copy that don't always meet the criteria. An example(attached below) is AAP with an expiry date of 4/16/2021.  I checked that sheet to make sure the cells where all of format "Date". So that's not an issue.

And finally note that based on the For loop that does the copy process, all of the "Sheetn" references should be contiguous.  There is no sort of any kind that occurs to change the order of things, so all "Sheet 7" rows should be together, all "Sheet8" rows together...

Any and all insights are greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Update_Active_Investments()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim BaseRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iDRow As Integer
    
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Active Investments")
    
    BaseRow = 0
    iDRow = 1
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (ws.CodeName = "Sheet1" Or ws.CodeName = "Sheet2" Or ws.CodeName = "Sheet3" Or ws.CodeName = "Sheet4" Or ws.CodeName = "Sheet5" Or ws.CodeName = "Sheet6") Then
            LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 3 To LastRow
                If Cells(i, 3).Value > Date And Cells(i, 23).Value = "Filled" Then
                    ws.Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & iDRow + BaseRow & ":Z" & iDRow + BaseRow)
                    ws2.Cells(i, 27) = ws.CodeName
                    iDRow = iDRow + 1
                End If
            Next i
            BaseRow = ws2.Range("C1:C500").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The resulting sheet is shown below.
[image]

Comment: Please add “code fence” lines to your question so the code is properly displayed. These are described in the sidebar; three back-ticks on a line.

Comment: Ctrl + k is the keyboard shortcut for coding segment, fyi

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way arround, instead of checking it's less than 6 I would check if it's more. additionally it would be much faster to interact less with the sheet but work more in memory. something like this:

```
Sub Update_Active_Investments()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, LastRow As Integer, BaseRow As Integer, iDRow As Integer
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Active Investments")
    
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, j As Long, jj As Long, arr
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 7 To Worksheets.Count
            If ws.CodeName = "Sheet" & i Then
                arr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(j, 3) > Date And arr(j, 23) = "Filled" Then
                        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(jj, 1), ws2.Cells(jj, 26)) = ws.Range(ws.Cells(j, 1), ws2.Cells(j, 26))
                        ws2.Cells(jj, 27) = ws.CodeName
                        jj = jj + 1
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

You could optimize further by not moving the range line by line on the sheet but rather assigning it to another array and dumping this to the sheet when you are done. Nevertheless, even when copying ranges you can just assign them to each other, no need to copy.